# tree command in eshell on Windows

Tags: eshell

The unix `tree` command gives a very good overview of the project/dir structure. Even Windows has its own version of `tree`.

When I run `tree` command in `eshll` on Windows, I got this error:

```
$ tree
Spawning child process: exec format error
```

It seems that `eshell` doesn't support the system (Windows) command. What should I do? Or is there any implementations for `eshell`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tree` is not a command built into `eshell`. If you run the command `which tree` you'll find that it's running the Windows version of `tree`, which it seems gives `eshell` some problems in its output format. Try downloading GNU `tree` for Windows from the project GnuWin32 [here](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/tree.htm).